# Passing closure in userInfo to NotificationCenter, getting cryptic messages from compiler at runtime

Tags: swift, foundation, notificationcenter

I'm trying to pass a closure in userInfo through NotificationCenter. The closures works as expected but I'm getting weird messages that I do not understand in runtime. What is the cause of this message?

The message is:

> 0x000000010292b350 [ProjectName]`partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> (@out ()) to @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () at <compiler-generated>

This is how I post the notification.

```swift
let closure: (() -> Void) = {
        print("TEST")
    }
        
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .test, 
    object: nil, 
    userInfo: ["closure" : closure ])
```

This is how I consume the notificaiton:

```swift
@objc private func test(_ notification: Notification) {
    let closure = notification.userInfo?["closure"] as? (() -> Void)
    closure?()
}
```

I'm using Swift 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't reproduce the error, but I would suggest wrapping the closure in a wrapper class. Things that need to round-trip into and out of Cocoa do better when they are NSObjects:

```
class Wrapper : NSObject {
    let closure : () -> Void
    init(closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.closure = closure
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let closure: (() -> Void) = {
            print("TEST")
        }
        let wrapper = Wrapper(closure: closure)
        let test = Notification.Name("Test")
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
            selector: #selector(testing), name: test, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: test,
            object: nil, userInfo: ["wrapper" : wrapper ])
    }

    @objc private func testing(_ notification: Notification) {
        let wrapper = notification.userInfo?["wrapper"] as? Wrapper
        wrapper?.closure()
    }
}
```